# Blue-Green Deployment in AWS with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am thinking to use Ansible to manage my AWS infrastructure; I have (2 servers with auto scaling).

I will deploy using `ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy-plats.yml --limit spring-boot`

Here my `deploy-plats.yml`

```
---
- hosts: bastion:apache:spring-boot
  vars:
  remote_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
  - name: Copies the .jar to the Spring Boot boxes
    copy: dest=~/ src=~/dev/plats/target/plats.jar mode=0777
  - name: Restarts the plats service
    service: name=plats state=restarted enabled=yes
    become: yes
        become_user: root
```

and I am wondering if using this technology will be a Blue-green deployment or the servers will be restarted at the same time, producing a downtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default, Ansible will try to manage all of the machines referenced
>   in a play in parallel. For a rolling updates use case, you can define
>   how many hosts Ansible should manage at a single time by using the
>   `serial` keyword: (maybe you look for something like this and not blue
>   green deployment)

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial: 1
```

[ansible-serial-link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html)

Also your playbook is not a blue green deployment, I suggest you to read about it.

> little bit. A blue/green deployment is a software deployment strategy
>   that relies on two identical production configurations that alternate
>   between active and inactive. One environment is referred to as blue,
>   and the duplicate environment is dubbed green. The two environments,
>   blue and green, can each handle the entire production workload and are
>   used in an alternating manner rather than as a primary and secondary
>   space. One environment is live and the other is idle at any given
>   time. When a new software release is ready, the team deploys this
>   release to the idle environment, where it is thoroughly tested. Once
>   the new release has been vetted, the team will make the idle
>   environment active, typically by adjusting a router configuration to
>   redirect application traffic. This leaves the alternate environment
>   idle.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ansible will run each task in paralell. You can set the play-level directive "serial" to force it to run the play on one and one node. This is described in detail here:
["Delegation, Rolling Updates, and Local Actions"](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size)

Answer (score 0):

serial tag must solve your problem. Limit the value to 1 so that the restart task will get executed in rolling fashion.